# changing characters.string from nil to ""

Tags: ios, swift

```
var addressTxtFldArray = addressTxtFld.text!.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
        if addressTxtFldArray.count == 1 {
            addressTxtFldArray[1] = ""
            addressTxtFldArray[2] = ""
            addressTxtFldArray[3] = ""
            addressTxtFldArray[4] = ""
            addressTxtFldArray[5] = ""
        } else if addressTxtFldArray.count == 2 {
            addressTxtFldArray[2] = ""
            addressTxtFldArray[3] = ""
            addressTxtFldArray[4] = ""
            addressTxtFldArray[5] = ""
        } else if addressTxtFldArray.count == 3 {
            addressTxtFldArray[3] = ""
            addressTxtFldArray[4] = ""
            addressTxtFldArray[5] = ""
        } else if addressTxtFldArray.count == 4 {
            addressTxtFldArray[4] = ""
            addressTxtFldArray[5] = ""
        } else {
            addressTxtFldArray[5] = ""
        }
        var cityTxtFldArray = cityTxtFld.text!.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
        if cityTxtFldArray.count == 1 {
            cityTxtFldArray[1] = ""
        }
        var stateTxtFldArray = stateTxtFld.text!.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
        if stateTxtFldArray.count == 1 {
            stateTxtFldArray[1] = ""
        }
        var addressTxtFldDestArray = addressTxtFldDest.text!.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
        if addressTxtFldDestArray.count == 1 {
            addressTxtFldDestArray[1] = ""
            addressTxtFldDestArray[2] = ""
            addressTxtFldDestArray[3] = ""
            addressTxtFldDestArray[4] = ""
            addressTxtFldDestArray[5] = ""
        } else if addressTxtFldDestArray.count == 2 {
            addressTxtFldDestArray[2] = ""
            addressTxtFldDestArray[3] = ""
            addressTxtFldDestArray[4] = ""
            addressTxtFldDestArray[5] = ""
        } else if addressTxtFldDestArray.count == 3 {
            addressTxtFldDestArray[3] = ""
            addressTxtFldDestArray[4] = ""
            addressTxtFldDestArray[5] = ""
        } else if addressTxtFldDestArray.count == 4 {
            addressTxtFldDestArray[4] = ""
            addressTxtFldDestArray[5] = ""
        } else {
            addressTxtFldDestArray[5] = ""
        }
        var cityTxtFldDestArray = cityTxtFldDest.text!.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
        if cityTxtFldDestArray.count == 1 {
            cityTxtFldDestArray[1] = ""
        }
        var stateTxtFldDestArray = stateTxtFldDest.text!.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
        if stateTxtFldDestArray.count == 1 {
            stateTxtFldDestArray[1] = ""
        }
```

Hello, so as you can see I am breaking down strings into individual words on the string, and then if they are empty, change them to "" instead of nil. However, it seems like this is still returning nil. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can do `addressTxtFldArray[1] = string()` or `addressTxtFldArray[1] = " "`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you're not getting "Index out of range" errors with this code.

If you simply want to make sure your addressTxtFldArray variable always has exactly 6 entries, I would suggest something like this:

```
 var addressTxtFldArray = (addressTxtFld.text!.characters
                           .split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init) 
                           + Array(count:6, repeatedValue:"")
                          )[0..<6]
```

Comment: That is exactly the error that I am getting. So, will that then make all of the empty values in the array ""? What this is suppose to be is an address finder, so some address's can be like "124 seasame street" or it could be "123 seasame beets road" which obviously have different word amounts, so thats why I needed to write code to handle this.

Comment: Yes all the empty values in the array will be "".   I'm assuming that you are using some kind of third party module that imposes these artificial constraints on the number of components in the address.  Otherwise there should be no reason to fill up the array with empty strings. You can always process arrays based on the effective number of elements they contain.

Comment: I did what you said for each of my variable statements, but unfortunately it is giving me an error saying "too complex to be solved in reasonable time"

Comment: That sometimes hapens when the compiler cannot figure out which data type to use inside an expression.  You can break it down in consecutive assignments to addressTxtFldArray with ....map(String.init) on the first line, then addressTxtFldArray = (addressTxtFldArray + Array(count:6, repeatedValue:"") )[0..<6] on a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the text field array to be field with "" instead of nil, I suggest you create a secondary array to save you from doing all the if comparisons and setting it to "".

```
var arrayContainer = [String](count: 10, repeatedValue: "")
let addressTxtFldArray = text.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)

for (index,value) in addressTxtFldArray.enumerate()
{
  arrayContainer[index] = value
}

print( arrayContainer)
```